# std::string xml string to object

Tags: c++, xml, string, xml-parsing

What would be the most effective way to take an XML string of type std::string and convert it to an in-memory XML object, the object structure is of no importance, what I'm after is whether I'd need to go through the string char by char and pick out all the pieces or if there is some easier way?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to use a library to do that.

If you want to do that yourself, you'll need to parse the string containing XML code. There are many ways to do that; easiest is probably a recursive-descent parser.

Comment: "Most effective" would still be to use someone else's already developed and debugged library.

Comment: @peoro - *you'll need to parse the string containing XML code* - really?  Many XML libraries will take a string and convert it into object model format.  MSXML will do that but it's a pill to use because it uses COM programming metaphors. Your basic point is correct, but recommendation for which one to use would also be useful I am sure.

Comment: With "If you want to do that yourself" I was meaning "if you don't want to relay on any XML library"...

Comment: Can anyone suggest a library?  Just saying 'use a library' is not very helpful.

Comment: @naspinski: [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) is a nice one, but you'll find thousands of XML libraries: many frameworks offer functions to work with XML files (eg: [QtXML module](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtxml.html)). Also look to the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Arabica: http://www.jezuk.co.uk/cgi-bin/view/arabica Of all XML libraries/wrappers I am aware of it is most std friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Try Expat, compact, user-friendly and free:
http://expat.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MSXML](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=993c0bcf-3bcf-4009-be21-27e85e1857b1&displaylang=en) for this, it will take the string and produce a DOM (Document Object Model) representation.  Documentation is OK but this is not the easiest library to use.  WIndows only of course.

Pros - reliable, widely used.
Cons - you have to learn COM programming model to a degree.  Not the most intuitive to use.

A simpler option would be [xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/).  Sample file parse code [here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/domprint-3.html), there are other samples as well. I've used both this and MSXML in different jobs.

Comment: @Tony - I don't blame you. You won't need that to use Xerces, or many of the others, I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/). Not a highly complicated library and easy to use. Portable, written in C but bindings to other languages available, and loads of examples to use and learn from.